# Formatting date params before create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My form is passing dates in the format "2 Apr 2012"

I understand I can format the individual params using something like this:

```
 @release_date = Date.parse(params[:release_date]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
 @original_release_date = Date.parse(params[:original_release_date]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
 @preorder_start_date = Date.parse(params[:preorder_start_date]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

But how do I then pass the formatted values to my create action?

```
 @product = @release.products.create(params[:product])
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have same field into the database then overwrite the value of params like :

```
params[:product][:release_date] = Date.parse(params[:release_date]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
params[:product][:original_release_date] = Date.parse(params[:original_release_date]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
params[:product][:preorder_start_date] = Date.parse(params[:preorder_start_date]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

@product = @release.products.create(params[:product])
```

Comment: I can see how this should work but i'm getting a "TypeError in ProductsController#create / can't dup NilClass"

Comment: just put the condition before parsing date like : Date.parse(params[:preorder_start_date]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") if !params[:preorder_start_date].nil?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.........

```
   @release_date = Date.parse(params[:release_date]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
   @original_release_date = Date.parse(params[:original_release_date]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
  @preorder_start_date = Date.parse(params[:preorder_start_date]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

And then

```
  @product.release_date = @release_date
  @product.original_release_date =  @original_release_date
  @product.preorder_start_date  = @preorder_start_date 
  @product.save
```

Done!!!!!!!!!!